# What is the difference between == and === in php

Tags: php, syntax, comparison

Is there any difference between `==` and `===` in PHP? Both seem to work fine for me when i use them in a conditional statement.

Answer (score 22):

- `$a == $b`

**Equal true**: if `$a` is equal to
`$b`, after type juggling.

---

- `$a === $b`

**Identical true**: if `$a` is equal to `$b`, and they are of the **same type**.

Comment: what is your mean of *same type* ? iIf `$a == $b` be true, then certainly they are of the same type. is it not ? can you give me a example that they  be `==` (true) but `===` (false) ?

Comment: @Sajad here http://www.php.net/manua/en/language.operators.comparison.php is a lot of examples

Comment: @Shafizadeh http://www.7codes.info/post/4/difference-between-==-and-=== in example "22" is string and 22 is integer. They are not the same type because one is string, another integer. With `==` they are equal, but with `===` are not equal

Answer (score 8):

#### Identical:

`$a === $b`

`TRUE` if `$a` is `equal` to `$b`, and they are of the same type. (introduced in `PHP 4`)

#### Equal:

`$a == $b`

`TRUE` if `$a` is equal to `$b` after type juggling.

Read here for more:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php