# php long numbers in string comparison

Tags: php, string, comparison

```
var_dump("555555555555555555555" == "555555555555555555553"); //bool(true)
var_dump("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" == "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab"); //bool(false)
```

Why does this happen?

I know I can use

```
var_dump(strcmp("555555555555555555555", "555555555555555555553") == 0); //bool(false)
```

But why the first row returns `true`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between == and === in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316784/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a side effect of type-coercing.
There's an [article on phpsadness](http://phpsadness.com/sad/47) about it.
Basically, the strings in the comparison are converted to numeric types, and due to precision loss, appear to be equal.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel, absolutely. I have a strict rule to never use `==` at all.

Comment: I'm just stuck by a higher PHP version. Always use `===` to compare those strings.

Answer (score 1):

In your first row

```
var_dump("555555555555555555555" == "555555555555555555553");
```

it is **true**

Why because, the type-coercing comparison operators will coerce both operands to floats if they both look like numbers, even if they are both already strings

This bug is discussed [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54547)