# Wrong PHP string equality

Tags: php, string, equality, digits

For some reason, PHP decided that if:

```
$a = "3.14159265358979326666666666"

$b = "3.14159265358979323846264338"
```

`$a == $b` is true.

Why is that, and how can I fix that?

It ruins my code.

Answer (score 7):

### The Problem

PHP converts strings (if possible) to numbers ([source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)). Floating points have a limited precision ([source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)). So `$a == $b` because of rounding errors.

### The Fix

Use `===` or `!==`.

### Try it

```
<?php

$a = "3.14159265358979326666666666";
$b = "3.14159265358979323846264338";

if ($a == $b) {
    echo "'$a' and '$b' are equal with ==.<br/>";
} else {
    echo "'$a' and '$b' are NOT equal with ==.<br/>";
}

if ($a === $b) {
    echo "'$a' and '$b' are equal with ===.<br/>";
} else {
    echo "'$a' and '$b' are NOT equal with ===.<br/>";
}
?>
```

Results in

```
'3.14159265358979326666666666' and '3.14159265358979323846264338' are equal with ==.
'3.14159265358979326666666666' and '3.14159265358979323846264338' are NOT equal with ===.
```

### Note

When you want to do high precision mathematics, you should take a look at [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

Answer (score 4):

You could use `===` in the equality test.

```
$a = "3.14159265358979326666666666";
$b = "3.14159265358979323846264338";

if($a===$b)
{
    echo "ok";
}
else
{
    echo "nope";
}
```

This code will echo `nope`.

Comparing with `==` is a loose comparison, and both strings will be converted to numbers, and not compared right away.

Using `===` will perform a string comparison, without type conversion, and will give you the wanted result.

You can find more explanations in the PHP manual:

- *[PHP type comparison tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)*
- *[Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)*

Comment: Ah damn. Should have written mine as an answer instead of a comment! +1 to you anyway :)

Comment: Also this can helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161722/php-long-numbers-in-string-comparison

Answer (score 1):

Read [PHP: Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch
>   statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison
>   is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the
>   value.

Others have recommended BC Math, but if you are doing floating point comparisons, the traditional way of comparing numbers is to see if they are the same to a reasonable error level

```
$epsilon = 1.0e-10;
if (abs($a - $b) < $epsilon) then {
    // they're the same for all practical purposes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$a === $b` instead; you should never use `==` for string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You should not to compare a float variable like that.

Try this:

```
bccomp($a, $b, 26)
```

Comment: Re *"Try this"*: Perhaps explain it instead? E.g., what is the magic number "26" supposed to do? Why not 25 or 27? Without looking at the documentation, I would expect that it should be 15, 16 or 17, corresponding to [8-byte IEEE floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64). Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22709511/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).