# PHP get value from file function acts wierd

Tags: php

The function reads two strings from file data.db (utf-8). The file contains strings: '123' and '123'. I checked it via ECHO and it displays the content correctly. Thus im sure the problem is not in the file.

When I try to match the values with the file the variable $access never change.

```
 //got data from $_POST....

function au_check($login,$psw){
$f = file('data.db');
$l = $f[0];
$p = $f[1];

$access = 'fail';

if ($login==$l && $psw==$p){ 
    $access='CHANGED';
}
return $access;

}

echo (au_check($_POST['login'],$_POST['pass'])); //returns FAIL :((((
```

BUT! If i change my values DIRECTLY in code IT WORKS...
    //got data from $_POST....

```
function au_check($login,$psw){
    $f = file('data.db');
    $l = '123';
    $p = '123';

    $access = 'fail';

    if ($login==$l && $psw==$p){ 
        $access='CHANGED';
    }
   return $access;

}

echo (au_check($_POST['login'],$_POST['pass'])); //returns CHANGED.
?>
```

plz help! how to fix and what is wrong? that's so weird ....

Comment: What's the output of `print_r($f);`? You might have to `trim()` things up

Comment: It might be possible that `$login/$psw` and `$l/$p`both doesn't have same datatype values, so you may need to do **type casting** before doing comparision

Comment: print_r ($f) Array
(
    [0] => 123

    [1] => 123

)

Comment: Sorry and `var_dump($f);` ?

Comment: @Haridarshan `===` = Identical true, `==` = value true. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6316807/2518525). (*You don't need to cast*)

Comment: THANK YOU! the problem was in some whitespaces after reading... hmm never had this problem before. Untill i moved to Brackets editor.

Answer (score 1):

`file` returns the lines, *complete with newline character*.

Use something like this to trim them off (the `trim` function is too heavy-handed):

```
$lines = file('data.db');
$f = array_map(function($line) {return rtrim($line,"\r\n");},$lines);
```

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky That would fall under the heavy-handedness that `trim` has. Values in a "one-value per line" format should be allowed to have trailing spaces. In this case, we should *only* strip the end-of-line itself.