# error occurred when comparing string with php

Tags: php

```
<?php
    var_dump('00E73694765433'=='0');  //true
    var_dump('0134b40fsbi94u8'=='0'); //false
    var_dump('0134b40fsbi94u8'=='134'); //false
    echo PHP_EOL;
    var_dump(is_numeric('00E73694765433'));//true
    var_dump(is_numeric('0134b40fsbi94u8'));//false
?>
```

As the code showed,I got into a problem when I compared two strings.I could not understand how the result came even I refered to the official manual. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    var_dump('00E73694765433'==='0');  //false
    var_dump('0'==='0');  //true
    var_dump('0134b40fsbi94u8'==='0'); //false
    var_dump('0134b40fsbi94u8'==='134'); //false
    var_dump('0134b40fsbi94u8'==='0134b40fsbi94u8'); //true
?>
```

Use === instead of ==

Comment: I just want to know why this happened,thank you anyway!

Comment: I got the answer. Because of the letter 'E',so the first string is transferred to '0',however the second is transferred to '134'. That is my answer,thank you!

Comment: == just checks value while === checks datatype.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316784/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-php